# Dimensionality reduction when number of samples is much larger than number of features

Tags: machine-learning, pca, dimensionality-reduction

I was wondering what happens when the number of samples is much larger (e.g. $\times 200\:000$ times more) than the number of features? Is there any recommended way of reducing the samples' dimensionality?

If the number of features is much more than the samples, this is known as the curse of dimensionality, we use PCA or any other form of dimensionality reduction to improve the results. What happens when we have the opposite situation?

Comment: This problem is named "big data". Pitfalls of having too many observations are: (a) more computational power needed, (b) your p-values get wildly significant and in many cases are just function of your sample.

Comment: How is (b) a pitfall? That just reflects that the data contains a tremendous amount of information about parameters of interest, under the assumption it's iid from some constant data generating process.

Comment: (b) is a pitfall because a lot of people misinterpret significant p-values when what is really important is effect size.

Comment: tziny, in opposite to the curse of dimensionality it is called the bless of cardinality.

Answer (score 3):

> I was wondering what happens when the number of samples is much more (x200000 times more) than the number of features? Is there any recommended way of reducing the samples' dimensionality?

If by 'reduce the samples' dimensionality' you mean 'reduce the number of samples', the simplest thing to do is just pick a random subset of the data and work with that.

If you really did mean 'reduce the samples' dimensionality', you might want to look at what're called "online methods" for feature extraction - things like incremental probabilistic PCA or SGD-trained autoencoders.

Comment: Re your second paragraph: I guess one can simply treat samples as "dimensions" (i.e. transpose the data matrix) and do a usual PCA.